# Cell Padding Balloons in Xcode 9

Tags: ios

The problem is that I'm getting too much of it in relation to line length and text-wrapping.

Here is the code I added to the view controller's viewDidLoad():

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Here's the code I added to the Message Cell's configureCell() function to try to solve the problem:

```
self.sizeToFit()
self.layoutIfNeeded()
```

And finally, here's a screen-shot of the constraints I've applied.
[Message Label constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rDvL.png)

Despite all of these attempts to solve the problem, my cells keep ballooning geometrically as I add more text. Any suggestions on a fix?

Edit: Here's what the problem looks like:
[Ballooning Cells Cemos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r52Ws.png)

Comment: I don't know if I understand what you said. Do you want that your cell resize when you add more text in message?

Comment: Have you tried constraining the label to the edges instead of the margins of the superview? i.e. Uncheck "Relative to margin"

Comment: A worthy suggestion... but I'm afraid the problem persists. (I wish I could another screen-shot to display what's going on.)

Comment: J. -- I want the cell to expand, sure. But as of now the rate of expansion isn't a simple 1:1 space/text ratio. It's more like a 5:1 ratio.